# Bokeh TextInput parameter to key-stroke listen

Tags: autocomplete, bokeh, textinput

I would like to use TextInput/Autocomplete widget in my dashboard and have it being able to listen to each action which is made there, not only after Enter-input or changing focus to another element.
My goal is to use Autocomplete widget for filtering dataframe where user could start inputting name of a row and it would be automatically corrected if df had capital letters in name of columns. 
In other words, df has a column "Price", user inputs "p", Autocomplete immediately corrects it (according to the name of potential column) to "P" and then user finishes inputting it.

As I can see here - https://bokeh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/releases.html
on July update (v.1.3.0) this capability was added to TextInput widget.
In details of commit there is line "new property "wait_commit" for the event listener". But this parameter doesn't exist and furthermore official Bokeh v.2.0.1 documentation knows nothing about this property at all.

Would be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait_commit` is in a commit description. What ends up in the source code is listed on the "Files changed" tab, and there's no `wait_commit` there.

What you need is the `TextInput.value_input` property. You can attach a callback to it, and it should be called on any input.

As for changing focus - I don't think it's possible with the built-in functionality. You would have to extend the existing `TextInput` and add a new event or property to it.